# scala: what's the difference between Any and AnyRef?

Tags: scala

Just curious about the difference between type `Any` and `AnyRef` in Scala.
Why does int belongs to `AnyVal` but string belongs to `AnyRef`?

For example:

```
val a: AnyVal = 3
val b: AnyRef = "1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the *Scala primitives* such as Int, Boolean etc extend `AnyVal` interface

And all the *Java primitives* or better say java objects which are in `java.lang` library extends `AnyRef`
interface

for more information read the [unified types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html) which says the following

> > AnyVal represents value types. There are nine predefined value types and they are non-nullable: Double, Float, Long, Int, Short, Byte, Char, Unit, and Boolean. Unit is a value type which carries no meaningful information. There is exactly one instance of Unit which can be declared literally like so: (). All functions must return something so sometimes Unit is a useful return type.
> >
> > AnyRef represents reference types. All non-value types are defined as reference types. Every user-defined type in Scala is a subtype of AnyRef. If Scala is used in the context of a Java runtime environment, AnyRef corresponds to java.lang.Object

And in your example `val b: AnyRef = "1"` `b` *immutable variable* is treated as *java.lang.Object dataType*.

Answer (score 15):

Any is the supertype of all types. Any has two direct subclasses: AnyVal and AnyRef.

AnyVal represents value types. There are nine predefined value types and they are non-nullable: Double, Float, Long, Int, Short, Byte, Char, Unit, and Boolean.

AnyRef represents reference types. All non-value types are defined as reference types. Every user-defined type in Scala is a subtype of AnyRef. String in scala equals to java.lang.String and is the subtype of AnyRef.

[structure of scala.Any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4e5t.png)