# Invoking java class from scala using reflection

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-collections

I am trying to use reflection to call my java method from a scala class.

I referred this post. [scala: what's the difference between Any and AnyRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402200/scala-whats-the-difference-between-any-and-anyref) and my "arg" passed from Scala is a List[AnyRef]

Scala

```
 val arg: List[AnyRef] = List ("a",Object B)
    val clazz = classLoader.loadClass("com.project.Hello")
    val clazzObject = clazz.newInstance()
    val myMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("HelloJava", classOf[List[AnyRef]])
    myMethod.setAccessible(true)
    val response = myMethod.invoke(clazzObject, arg)
```

Java

```
package com.project;
     public class Hello {
        public static String HelloJava (List<Object> arg) {
        }
```

While invoking this method, I am getting below exception - 
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.Project.Hello(scala.collection.immutable.List)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod**

However, calling scala class from scala works fine with the same method signature.

*Can someone please help in clarifying the concept and tell me what I am doing wrong?* How I can resolve this issue primarily by changing java class (if not, then changes to the scala class). I looked at other posts as well which refers to use javaconversions and javaconverters, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scala, the `List` imported by default is `scala.collection.immutable.List` (as you can see in the message); in Java, there's none, but this class likely imports  `java.util.List`. If the Java class used the Scala list, it would work (but Scala collections are basically unusable from Java).

So you should fix the Scala class to use `classOf[java.util.List[AnyRef]]` instead.

Reflection doesn't know anything about javaconversions and javaconverters, they aren't relevant.

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thanks for the response. I tried updating the code to val myMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, classOf[java.util.List[AnyRef]]). The initial error is gone but now I am getting this error -- "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch"

Comment: Of course the argument you need to pass must be a Java list too (and here you can use `.asJava` from `JavaConverters`).

Comment: Thanks so much, scala to java is a much easier conversion. By any chance, if I need the change on java code - can you help me with a sample code for this class with explanation. I am just curious to know. I looked at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578615/how-to-use-scala-collection-immutable-list-in-a-java-code but couldn't understand.

Comment: Basically, my answer would be "don't" (if you mean using Scala collections from Java). You can't use Java lambdas for Scala functions, you need to create the implicits manually...

Comment: Thanks! Learnt something new today.